# How to get a value from a json

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have to get the "media_id" value from the json that is sent to me from facebook, I tried everything but I can't.
how can I do?

```
<?php


$challenge = $_REQUEST['hub_challenge'];
$verify_token = $_REQUEST['hub_verify_token'];

// Set this Verify Token Value on my Facebook App
if ($verify_token === 'token') {

echo $challenge;

$readjson = file_get_contents('php://input');

//Decode JSON
 $data = json_decode($readjson, true);

//try get media_id value

 print_r($data[entry][changes][value][media_id]);

 //response code 200 - ok
 header('HTTP/1.0 200 OK');

} else {
  header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
}




 ?>
```

this is the json that is sent to me, I can't get the value "media_id"

```
{
    "object": "instagram",
    "entry": [{
        "id": "0",
        "time": 1573295665,
        "changes": [{
            "field": "story_insights",
            "value": {
                "media_id": "17887498072083520",
                "impressions": 444,
                "reach": 44,
                "taps_forward": 4,
                "taps_back": 3,
                "exits": 3,
                "replies": 0
            }
        }]
    }]
}
```

I thank you for the help you give me

Comment: `$data[entry][changes][value][media_id]` is missing quotes around all keys.

Comment: I corrected it, he replied with "Undefined index"

Comment: `entry` is an array as you can see. Dump the result of `$data` and you'll figure it out. This is extremely basic stuff, to be honest.

Comment: @Vincy see my answer for details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use key value in quotes, also you are not using indexes for arrays
Please go though php manual for json travesing using indexes and keys

```
$json = <<<XML
{
    "object": "instagram",
    "entry": [{
        "id": "0",
        "time": 1573295665,
        "changes": [{
            "field": "story_insights",
            "value": {
                "media_id": "17887498072083520",
                "impressions": 444,
                "reach": 44,
                "taps_forward": 4,
                "taps_back": 3,
                "exits": 3,
                "replies": 0
            }
        }]
    }]
}
XML;
$json = json_decode($json,true);
print_r($json["entry"][0]["changes"][0]["value"]["media_id"]);
```

in PHP variables without $ are constants and with $ are normal variables so your keys are bieng mistaken for constant variables

Comment: Undefined index: changes in /direcotry on line 15 (is the line where this code is located)

Comment: @Vincy see my updated answer with demo code , understand it

Comment: thanks, I'm a beginner with php and I've been very helpful, I solved it like this: print_r ($ data ["entry"] [0] ["changes"] [0] ["value"] ["media_id "]);

Comment: @Vincy no problem buddy :) I was also a beginner and I thourougly recommend you to read the php manual first as it is a great place for beginners, so you never have to go lost like this again.
All the best